Integral over the Riemann sphere

I was reading this wikipedia article and stuck to show that,
$$\frac{i}{\pi}\int \frac{dz\wedge d\bar z}{(1+|z|^2)^2}=2$$
after switching to polar coordinates. By Stokes' theorem, an exact form would integrate to $0$, so the cohomology class is nonzero.

we knew that,
$$
dz = dx + idy, \quad d\bar z = dx - idy
$$
where $dx$ and $dy$ are differentials of the real and imaginary parts of $z$ respectively. Then the expression become:
$$
\frac{i}{\pi}\int \frac{(dx + idy) \wedge (dx - idy)}{(1+|z|^2)^2}
$$
From the numerator we have:
\begin{align}
&= \frac{i}{\pi}\int \frac{dx \wedge dx - i(dx \wedge dy + dy \wedge dx) +dy \wedge dy}{(1+|z|^2)^2}\\
&= \frac{i}{\pi}\int \frac{- i(dx \wedge dy + dy \wedge dx)}{(1+|z|^2)^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{(dx \wedge dy + dy \wedge dx)}{(1+|z|^2)^2}
\end{align}
I assume I need to consider $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $dx \wedge dy+dy\wedge dx$ become $r(dr \wedge d\theta+d\theta\wedge dr)$ and $|z|^2=r^2$. But how to handle $r(dr \wedge d\theta+d\theta\wedge dr)$?

$dx\wedge dy + dy\wedge dx=0$, so that is not too promising.  Note that you made an error at the outset: $idy\wedge dx - i dx\wedge dy = -2i dx\wedge dy = -2i r\,dr\wedge d\theta$.

Thanks @TedShifrin. I fix the error and got the desire result $2$.

Great! Please accept the answer when you are done with this question, so that the question will no longer appear unanswered.
